# Paypal Rest API Payment or Braintree Payments

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, braintree, paypal-rest-sdk

I used the Paypal NVP API (Express checkout) for a long time and it worked fine. I'm now developing a new project and wanted to use the 'new' Rest API that Paypal recommends for new projects. I, however, find the documentation rather imprecise at some points and often contradictory.

I'm using their sandbox to test the payments and I noticed that the payments work fine, except that once I log in to the Paypal Buyer account, I can only select the PayPal balance to pay.

Is this a limitation of the Rest API? I want to clarify that I am based outside the US and I do not want to accept credit card payments on my own website (well, if there is no other solution, I would accept it). I'd rather have the user get redirected to the PayPal page and provide his credit card information over there. I do, however, want to give the option to the user to at least select from PayPal balance or credit card. (As I'm used to from the NVP API)

**UPDATE**
In the meantime, I've done a lot of additional research. On [the PHP SDK page](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK), they've added the following notice:

> Important: The PayPal REST API no longer supports new direct credit card integrations. Please instead consider Braintree Direct; which is, PayPal's preferred integration solution for accepting direct credit card payments in your mobile app or website. Braintree, a PayPal service, is the easiest way to accept credit cards, PayPal, and many other payment methods.

How should I understand the *direct credit card* integration? Is that the credit card payment on the PayPal website after being redirected onto that page or do they mean credit card payments where the card number is provided on ones own website?

I've got the impression, PayPal is entirely shifting to Braintree Payments. Even on the [official PayPal Developer website](https://developer.paypal.com), they propose Express Checkout for quick (client side only) integrations and Braintree Direct for other payments.

This is what I need:

- PHP integration of the API calls
- Payment methods: PayPal balance, Different Credit Cards
- eventually recurring payments

I **do not need**:

- Third party invoicing
- client management
- shipping address management

So my concrete questions would be:

- What's the difference between Braintree and PayPal payment methods (since they belong to the same organisation)?
- Should I use PayPal Rest API or Braintree solutions in my case?
- What are those PayPal limitations that they list on their website?

Has nobody got any experience in this domain? Even partial answers are welcome!

Comment: I'm super hung up on this also, I'm building a Rest API app to be used by Philippines Merchants. 

In regards to this question did you manage to find the answer "How should I understand the direct credit card integration? Is that the credit card payment on the PayPal website after being redirected onto that page or do they mean credit card payments where the card number is provided on ones own website?" Much appreciated!

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not. I have not yet tested it in production, either. I did however find that the documentation is being updated and some explanations are way clearer now than they were before. But, still looking for the right answers to the questions. I'll keep you updated as soon as I know more.

Answer (score 5):

I have partial answer, as I am also in the process of choosing between BrainTree, PayPal Rest API, and Express checkout.

I'm here to answer **"How should I understand the direct credit card integration?"**

I'm no expert on the subject, but during my recent work at the area of integration with checkout systems, I've learned this:
One of the types of credit-cards is called "direct credit card". It means that it is directly connected with a bank account - when it is billed, the money is instantly transfered from the connected bank-account to the merchant. This is different than how most credit-cards work - most will only charge the bank-acoount at the beginninng of the next month.

I've come accross situations where direct cards behave differently than regular credit-cards.
For instance - the checkout-system I integrate with doesn't allow to monthly-bill a direct card. direct card on a monthly payment plan have to be billed manually.

So for me, the PayPal announcement you qouted means a lot - I need to support direct credit cards, hence I'm choosing **BrainTree**. Thanks!

Note to moderators:
I originally wanted to post this as a comment to the question, becuase I thought it would help the OP. I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I posted an Answer.

Comment: A partial answer, with some insights and "observations from the wild" are an accepted participation in the answering process here at StackOverflow; especially while no better complete answer is available.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @pinkasey. I'm however not sure if PayPal isn't using `direct credit card payment` as `direct credit card accepting on your own website without being redirected to PayPal`. You may be right, of course. These PayPal documentations are completely unclear.

Comment: I think you're right, @Lozik - 
I've been browsing through PayPal documentation all day, and came accross this:


`Important: The use of the PayPal REST /payments APIs to accept credit card payments is restricted. Instead, you can accept credit card payments with Braintree Direct. `

here:
[https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/)

Comment: Thank you @pinkasey, and again, the PayPal docs are unclear: They do not specify what they mean by `restricted`, neither if they mean payment by credit card in general or only the credit card payments that can be done without leaving the own website. I think the best we can do is test, test, test and test again. Until now, I've tested the REST API with their sandbox and I didn't come across any restriction. (see my use case in my initial question) (1/2)

Comment: The only thing I noticed was that if the user doesn't log in, he can pay by credit card but once he logged in, he can't anymore. Don't know if thats an issue with my precise API settings, sandbox user settings or a wanted behaviour. But unless someone from PayPal tells us exactly what they mean, it's quite hard to find out. If I remember correctly, their developper-support redirects to stackoverflow. (2/2)

Comment: I see this restriction on their v1 REST API's, but I don't see the message on their v2 REST API page. Anyone know if credit card processing is restricted on V2 REST API's?
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v2/
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1/